# append new column identifying matching dates of datetime from columns in different dataframes (of different lengths)

Tags: python, dataframe, compare, match

I am trying to add a new column to df2 to identify the matches between the dates in the two dataframe date columns. When there is a match on the dates (time not important for matching) print '1' in the column 'Match'. Below are the two dataframes and the desired output which I do not know how to achieve.

```
    df1:
              date          
    0  2019-05-03 12:22:03
    1  2019-05-06 13:56:00
    2  2019-05-08 11:25:53
    3  2019-05-09 06:11:14
    4  2019-05-13 23:36:18

    df2:
               date         Location
    0   2019-05-09 12:00:00 Area_A
    1   2019-05-10 14:00:00 Area_B
    2   2019-05-11 13:00:00 Area_C
    3   2019-05-12 11:00:00 Area_D
    4   2019-05-13 12:00:00 Area_A
    5   2019-05-14 14:00:00 Area_C
    6   2019-05-15 12:00:00 Area_B
    7   2019-05-16 12:00:00 Area_A
    8   2019-05-17 13:00:00 Area_A
    9   2019-05-18 18:00:00 Area_B

    Desired output df2:
                date            Location   Match
    0      2019-05-09 12:00:00  Area_A      1
    1      2019-05-10 14:00:00  Area_B      
    2      2019-05-11 13:00:00  Area_C      
    3      2019-05-12 11:00:00  Area_D      
    4      2019-05-13 12:00:00  Area_A      1
    5      2019-05-14 14:00:00  Area_C      
    6      2019-05-15 12:00:00  Area_B      
    7      2019-05-16 12:00:00  Area_A      
    8      2019-05-17 13:00:00  Area_A      
    9      2019-05-18 18:00:00  Area_B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both dfs create another column "_date" which has only dates and no time part.

```
df1["_dates"] = column with only dates (may be df1['dates'].dt.date)
df2["_dates"] = column with only dates (may be df2['dates'].dt.date)
df1["Match"] = 1
```

Now merge these two dataframes on "_dates"

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='_dates',right_on='_dates',how='right')
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance with this. For the first part I used `df1["_dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates']).dt.date` and `df2["_dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates']).dt.date`
However, I would like to get df2 'date' column back to column position 0, the output has moved this column to position 2

Comment: If the order of columns from left to right is A,B,C then they can shuffled by df = df[[B,C,A]]

Comment: Shifting the order was much easier than I expected. Thanks